# Keep Project Running on IIS Express when i exit visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express

Im Trying IIS Express out and cant figure out if its possible to keep the Project Running on the IIS Express server when i exit visual studio 2010.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Visual Studio exit, it stops all the IIS Express processes it started. Probably you should start the site you are interested in from command line after VS exit(use /site switch). Following URL may help http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/